# CoreBluetooth IOS pairing security issues

Tags: ios, swift, security, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to implement hard security connection between 2 BLE devices.

From official specification(https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/bluetooth-pairing-part-1-pairing-feature-exchange/)
I got that I have few ways to pairing Legacy and Secure Connection, includes key exchange methods - (just works, oob, passentry and numeric comparison).

But as I understood in CoreBluetooth framework I can't manage the way to devices are connecting. The way how peripheral and central are connected is hide from me and I can't hope is security way.
I found few posts: someone says - CoreBluetooth supports only just works, passentry, numeric comparison methods, but anyway we cant determine what method we are using.

Is there any ways to choice what type of connection and key exchange method I want to use in CoreBluetooth?

As example - I want to use Secure Connection with "just works" method

Comment: Core Bluetooth does not support bonding with "just works". You need to have the user enter a passcode or compare the passcode displayed on your peripheral. The bonding method that is used is determined by the peripheral.

Comment: @Paulw11 is there only passentry, numeric comparison methods? How CoreBluetooth determine what way should used - passentry or numeric comparison?

Comment: @Paulw11 and also how I can determine what type of connection is using legacy or secure? Numeric comparison exchange supposedly means we are using secure connection right?

Comment: You don't have any visibility of the process. Your peripheral indicates that encryption is required for a characteristic and what types of bonding it supports.  ios takes care of the pairing/bonding process.

Comment: @Paulw11 and could I guarantee high security level during data exchange?

Comment: @Paulw11 iOS supports and will use Just Works if the I/O capabilities of the peripheral are No input/No output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an iOS GATT client app developer, you don't have any control over the pairing or bonding process, in the current version of iOS at least.

When running iOS as central, it will initiate pairing either if the characteristic you are trying to interact with requires encryption, or the remote device sends an "SMP Security Request".

The used mechanism (legacy/secure connections, just works, passkey, numeric comparison etc.) will be based on the highest possible security that both devices support in common. iOS supports all features and thus the highest possible security (except oob/nfc pairing) so the chosen mechanism and security will therefore be based entirely on what the peripheral supports. If the peripheral that iOS connects to supports only Legacy Just Works, then that's the mechanism that will be used. If it supports LESC with Numeric Comparison, then that mechanism will be used. There is no way for the app developer to lower the security that iOS indicates it supports, to for example force Just Works if the remote device has a display or keyboard.

Unfortunately, from what I know, you don't know from the app's perspective the current security level that is actually in use though...

Comment: Well, thanks, great answer. I've noted some interesting thing, when I use encryption on characteristics it's occurring numeric comparison(when I should compare and accept 6 digits number on my central and peripheral screens, also it should be secure connection), and when I use nonencryption characteristics it's occurring "Just works"(I didn't see any popup windows or confirmation windows). Do you agree? And did you implement own TLS over existing BLE?

Comment: If you only use characteristics that don't require on iOS and you don't get any popup, no pairing will occur. Note that BLE can run without pairing being performed. "Just Works" refers to the specific pairing method that performs pairing, but doesn't have any way to ensure the correct devices are actually paired instead of a MITM. The "Just Works" method will be used when one of the devices doesn't have a keyboard/display or oob method. I have implemented TLS clients but not for the purpose of running over BLE.

Comment: OOB is not supported in CoreBluetooth as I know. Oh therefore I can't have "Just Works" method a priory because I have devices with displays and keyboard. Thanks